# Javascript -Processing Multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array

```
Arrayinarray=[];
let options = driver.findElements(By.css("[section='trim'] select"));
options.then(swap=>{
    swap.map((key)=>{
        var s=key.findElements(By.css("option"));
        s.then(mt=>{
            Arrayinarray.push(mt)
        })
    })

});
```

this is my selenium code.

I have to get each element of the array in correct order

For example.

```
var Arrayinarray=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6,5],[7,8,9],[1,6,3],[1,5,7][1,2,2],[7,2,9,3]];
```

Expected output:

```
1471117 1471112 1471119 1471113 1471127 1471122
1471129 1471123 1471127 1471122 1471129 1471123
...
```

I have to permutate the combination of this multidimensional array. I placed many `for` loops and `map` functions. However, it does not work.

Comment: Please show us your code.

Comment: @AyyappanRK No, don't put the code in the comments. Edit your question and put it there..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take a iterative approach by collecting all part arrays and take the final arrays for getting a number back.

```js
var values = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 5], [7, 8, 9], [1, 6, 3], [1, 5, 7], [1, 2, 2], [7, 2, 9, 3]],
    result = values
        .reduce((a, b) => a.reduce((r, v) => r.concat(b.map(w => [].concat(v, w))), []))
        .map(s => +s.join(''));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

The number of results can quickly grow large. In your case it will have 3*4*3*3*3*3*4 results, i.e. 3888 results, but making some of the sub arrays larger, and/or adding more of them multiplies the number of results quickly.

You could use a [generator function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*) and then select the first X results from it, or all of them (which I do below):

```js
function * generateCombis(arr) {
    if (arr.length === 1) return yield * arr[0];
    const shift = 10**(arr.length-1);
    for (let val of arr[0]) {
        for (let val2 of generateCombis(arr.slice(1))) yield val*shift+val2
    }
}
// Example
var Arrayinarray=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6,5],[7,8,9],[1,6,3],[1,5,7], [1,2,2],[7,2,9,3]];

const result = Array.from(generateCombis(Arrayinarray));
console.log(result);
```

Using the spread syntax, you could make the function take the subarrays as separate arguments (instead of taking a nested array), which makes some parts of the code more readable (but that is debatable):

```js
function * generateCombis(current, ...rest) {
    if (!rest.length) return yield * current;
    const shift = 10**rest.length;
    for (let val of current) {
        for (let val2 of generateCombis(...rest)) yield val*shift+val2
    }
}
// Example
var Arrayinarray=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6,5],[7,8,9],[1,6,3],[1,5,7], [1,2,2],[7,2,9,3]];

const result = Array.from(generateCombis(...Arrayinarray));
console.log(result);
```